# IOS Tab Bar Controller for Buttons (not tabs)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working on an app and I would like to use the tab bar controller styling, but without the tabs. I would like it so that when I click on a tab button a function is run, but I don't want it to jump to a new tab. Is this possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** it is possible.

Implement the [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol's `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method execute your code and return **`NO`**.

#### Example

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
     // Do your stuff here.

    return NO;
}
```